# Merge 2 XML & Extract this data using java and store it in db table

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to Java and I want to do the following task. Please guide me 2 do the same.

I want to write source code in Java (core Java or servlets) for the following task.

Use Objects, Data Structures, Interfaces, Thread pools, Connection pools where applicable.
Perform any validations if needed or wherever applies :

1. Let us say there are 2 xml files:

First xml:

```
<geodata>
 <person name="tom">
       <address>2344 States Drive, MA 01213, USA</address>
       <phonenumber>333-222-2222</phonenumber>
 </person>
 <person name="mat">
       <address>2345 Gates Drive, PA 11213, USA</address>
       <phonenumber>444-222-2222</phonenumber>
 </person>
</geodata>
```

Second xml:

```
<salarydata>
 <person name="mat">
       <salary>$3000</salary>
       <pension>$500</pension>
 </person>
 <person name="tom">
       <salary>$3500</salary>
       <pension>$700</pension>
 </person>
</salarydata>
```

From the above 2 xmls, form a single xml, say persondata.xml (through a Java
program, that takes the above 2 files as input) that looks like this:

```
<persondata>
  <person name="tom">
       <address>2344 States Drive, MA 01213, USA</address>
       <phonenumber>333-222-2222</phonenumber>
       <salary>$3500</salary>
       <pension>$700</pension>
  </person>
  <person name="mat">
       <address>2345 Gates Drive, PA 11213, USA</address>
       <phonenumber>444-222-2222</phonenumber>
       <salary>$3000</salary>
       <pension>$500</pension>
  </person>
</persondata>
```

1. Extract this data, using Java, from the persondata.xml and store in a persondata db table.
   Form your own persondata table structure (keeping the above persondata.xml metadata as reference).
   The db is in SQL Server
2. Write a html form that accepts some keywords from the user for each db field (for example, States Drive or 333 or $700) and a corresponding action Servlet that searches the persondata db table and prints/echos the matching record on to the user screen (in this example case, tom's record).

Pl. use relevant tools / components such as AJAX, J Query in this exercise, wherever you think is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code using JDOM:

```
Document xml1 = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader("<geodata>\n"
                + " <person name=\"tom\">\n"
                + "       <address>2344 States Drive, MA 01213, USA</address>\n"
                + "       <phonenumber>333-222-2222</phonenumber>\n"
                + " </person>\n"
                + " <person name=\"mat\">\n"
                + "       <address>2345 Gates Drive, PA 11213, USA</address>\n"
                + "       <phonenumber>444-222-2222</phonenumber>\n"
                + " </person>\n"
                + "</geodata>"));
        Document xml2 = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader("<salarydata>\n"
                + " <person name=\"mat\">\n"
                + "       <salary>$3000</salary>\n"
                + "       <pension>$500</pension>\n"
                + " </person>\n"
                + " <person name=\"tom\">\n"
                + "       <salary>$3500</salary>\n"
                + "       <pension>$700</pension>\n"
                + " </person>\n"
                + "</salarydata>"));

        List<Element> geodata = xml1.getRootElement().getChildren();
        List<Element> salarydata = xml2.getRootElement().getChildren();
        //Element root = new Element("persondata");
        for (Element e : geodata) {
            for (Element e2 : salarydata) {
                if (e.getAttributeValue("name").equals(e2.getAttributeValue("name"))) {
                    e.addContent(e2.removeContent());
                }
            }
        }
        Element rootNode = xml1.getRootElement();
        rootNode.setName("persondata");
        new XMLOutputter().output(xml1, System.out);
    }
```

Comment: There are various way of doing that.  You can either pass the entire xml to a stored procedure which will parse the xml and insert the data in the table or you can  use java to loop through the xml and insert the data individually.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer for my own question, this works well.

```
package com.techassignment;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Class1 {
    static public void main(String[] arg)
    {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Document doc2 = null;
    {
    try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\mkar\\workspace\\techassignment - new\\src\\com\\techassignment\\1st.xml"));
            doc2 = db.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\mkar\\workspace\\techassignment - new\\src\\com\\techassignment\\2nd.xml"));
            NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");

            Node nodeSalary = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0), true);
            Node nodePension = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("pension").item(0), true);
            Node nodeSalary1 = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(1), true);
            Node nodePension1 = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("pension").item(1), true);

            ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeSalary);
            ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodePension);
            ndListFirstFile.item(1).appendChild(nodeSalary1);
            ndListFirstFile.item(1).appendChild(nodePension1);

          TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
          Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
          transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  

          DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
          StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
          transformer.transform(source, result); 


          Writer output = null ;      
          output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\mkar\\workspace\\techassignment - new\\src\\com\\techassignment\\testFinal.xml"));
          String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();

          output.write(xmlOutput);

          output.close();
          System.out.println("XML Merged");

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e4.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    }
}
```